# Question about split coequaliser

Tags: category-theory

Let $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ be left adjoint to $G: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. Consider the unit $\eta$ and counit $\varepsilon$ of this adjunction.

Is it true that $GFG \varepsilon_B \circ \eta_{GFGB} = 1_{GFGB}$?

There is a split co-equaliser diagram in my notes, but I suspect that a couple of the arrows might be the wrong way round - the above morphism is equal to $\eta_{GB} \circ G\varepsilon_B$, which is backwards from the $\Delta$ identities. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could include the diagram from your notes in your question.
It might be easier to guess from there. What comes to my mind is to apply
$GF$ to the triangular equation $G\varepsilon \circ \eta G = 1_G$ and
evaluate the resulting natural maps at the object $B$. This would give
$GFG\varepsilon_B \circ GF\eta_{GB} = 1_{GFGB}$.

Comment: Turns out I wrote my diagram the wrong way round in my notes. I would have drawn the diagram but im not sure how to do them on this site in LaTeX.

Comment: [See this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9401/79365) regarding commutative diagrams on this site.... Also, what is to be done with this question, are you still looking for an answer?